# Select range in timestamps and create new column containing corresponding year season bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select range between 2 timestamps from DateTime column, create new column CropYear and apply 2019 for the first selected range and 2020 for the second  one.

Desired Output:

```
DateTime                  CropYear

'2018-11-16 00:00:00'       2019
...                         2019
'2019-10-14 23:59:59'       2019
'2019-10-15 00:00:00'       2020
...                         2020
*CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()*       2020
```

I tried with this query, but it seems like CASE does not support timestamps:

```
select SerialNumber, DateTime,
case DateTime
when DateTime BETWEEN '2018-11-16 00:00:01' AND '2019-10-14 23:59:59' then 2019
when DateTime BETWEEN '2019-10-15 00:00:00' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() then 2020
else "error"
end
as CropYear
from `xx.yyy`
```

Comment: just remove the first datetime after the case:

select SerialNumber, DateTime,
case
when DateTime BETWEEN '2018-11-16 00:00:01' AND '2019-10-14 23:59:59' then 2019
when DateTime BETWEEN '2019-10-15 00:00:00' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() then 2020
else "error"
end
as CropYear
from `xx.yyy`

should work

Answer (score 1):

How about just extracting the year function with an offset?

```
with t as(
      select timestamp('2018-11-16 00:00:00') as dt union all
      select timestamp('2019-10-14 23:59:59') union all
      select timestamp('2019-10-14 00:00:00') union all
      select timestamp('2019-10-15 00:00:00') union all
      select timestamp('2019-10-16 00:00:00') union all
      select current_timestamp
     )
select t.*,
       extract(year from timestamp_add(dt, interval 78 day)
              ) as crop_year
from t;
```

This eliminates the need for the `case` expression.

The "78" days is a magic number of days.  Add it to Oct 15 and you get Jan 1 -- the following year.

One note -- which is not directly related to the question -- is to be careful.  `TIMESTAMP` in BigQuery is in UTC (think London time basically).  I am guessing that you care more about a particular timezone.  If timezones are an issue, then ask a new question.